# Add delay to a hover:display property in native tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a sidebar that gets bigger on hover. In that sidebar, I have divs that contains extra-content which is only displayed when the sidebar is hovered. The code below works well:

HTML file

```
    <!--Sidebar-->
    <div class="group w-16 bg-blue-700 hover:w-44">Sidebar
        <div>Item 1
            <span class="hidden group-hover:inline">Item 1: Details</span>
        </div>
        <div>Item 2
            <span class="hidden group-hover:inline">Item 2: Details</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {},
    extend: {},
    variants: {
        extend: {
            width: ['hover'],
            display: ['group-hover'],
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

However, I would like to create a nice transition when the sidebar is hovered so that it gets bigger smoothly. I do this by changing the HTML file to -->

New HTML file

```
    <!--Sidebar-->
    <div class="group w-16 bg-blue-700 hover:w-44 transition-all">Sidebar
        <div>Item 1
            <span class="hidden group-hover:inline">Item 1: Details</span>
        </div>
        <div>Item 2
            <span class="hidden group-hover:inline">Item 2: Details</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Doing so, now, there is small bug when the sidebar is hovered: the extra content is displayed before the  sidebar reaches its full-size.
I need to add a delay to the display of the extra content. Ideally, the sidebar would first gets bigger smoothly and reach its full-size, and only then the extra-content would appear. Is there a way to do so in native tailwind css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  [Ali javanmardi hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498505/13371166), I managed to achieve what I wanted. The main findings are:

- Need to use Absolute positioning for Items Details in the sidebar
- Adding a delay on a transition such as `group-hover:visible delay-150` does not work in this specific case because this would lead the details to disappear after the sidebar is closed (because delay is applied at Start and End)

Instead, I created a custom animation of 1s, where the first "transition" keyframes happens at 15%, thus creating effectively a delay from 0% to 15%, combined with `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` Below is my code.

HTML file

```
    <!--Sidebar-->
    <div class="group w-16 bg-blue-700 hover:w-44 transition-all">Sidebar
        <div class="relative">Item 1
            <span class="absolute opacity-0 invisible group-hover:animate-tooltip_show ml-2">Item 1: Details</span>
        </div>
        <div class="relative">Item 2
            <span class="absolute opacity-0 invisible group-hover:animate-tooltip_show ml-2">Item 2: Details</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        tooltip_show: {
          '0%' : { visibility: 'hidden', opacity: '0'},
          '15%' : { visibility: 'hidden', opacity: '0'},
          '100%' : { visibility: 'visible', opacity: '100'},
        }
      },
      animation: {
        tooltip_show: 'tooltip_show 1s ease forwards',
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      width: ['hover'],
      animation: ['group-hover'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this I did a simple hack for it.

As you may find yourself, tailwindcss-> group-hover:visible class represents:

```
.group:hover .group-hover\:visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

So I changed group-hover:visible to xgroup-hover:visible and added some animation instead of original tailwindcss:

```
@keyframes tooltip-show {
  0%   {opacity: 0;}
  5%   {visibility: visible;}
  25%  {opacity: 50;}
  50%  {opacity: 75;}
  100% {opacity: 100;}
}
.group:hover .xgroup-hover\:visible {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-name: tooltip-show;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

this simple hack worked for me :)

So you can follow same way for your desired group-hover:inline class and add your own animation keyframes as you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I'm new to tailwind and did not manage to implement it. First, could you please confirm my understanding that this code should be copied to tailwind.css file (under @utilities;). Second, could you please explain the trick with using xgroup-hover instead of group-hover? Finally, I don't get how this should be used with group-hover:inline... Sorry for all these late questions :(

Comment: @kenshuri, I simply added that code in my html file as I used it in that file.
changing group-hover class name was just a try to ignore tailwind normal behavior and apply my own class instead. It does not modify tailwind at all, it just make a css class for you that you can apply your own style.

You can apply whatever css style you want instead of default tailwind behavior, just remember to add your css class name after tailwind css class name to control the order of styles apply by css (css styles will apply from first to last and so the last style is what you will receive finally)

Comment: Thanks again @Ali for your help. I finally managed to achieve exactly what I wanted. The main point is that I need to use absolute positioning for the Items Details, relative to the sidebar. From that, it was mainly playing with the animations until  I found the good one. I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation without using custom animation. You just need to add a delay when the parent is hovered, and reset the delay back to zero when the parent is not hovered.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
  @layer components {
    #container {
      @apply flex flex-col items-center gap-2 mt-4;
    };

    #button {
      @apply bg-blue-400 text-white p-1 rounded;
    };

    #tooltips {
      @apply bg-green-400 p-0.5 w-24 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 
             translate-y-10 transition-opacity rounded;
    };
  };
</style>

<!-- Ignore previous code block, it's just for styling -->

<div id='container'>
  <h1>Hover with delay tailwindcss<h1>
  <button id='button' class='relative group'
  >Hover me
    <span id='tooltips' class='absolute 
                               opacity-0 
                               delay-0 
                               group-hover:opacity-100 
                               group-hover:delay-300'
    >I'm here </span>
  </button>
</div>
```